# No smooth transition of :enter and :leave Angular animations

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I'd like a smooth slide in and slide out animation using Angular animations. I am using `ngSwitch` to show/hide these components. The incoming component pushes the previous one up before it disappears out of view. I've tried adding a delay but this does not resolve the issue.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container" [ngSwitch]="counter">
  <div @slideInOut *ngSwitchCase="1"></div>
  <div @slideInOut *ngSwitchCase="2"></div>
  <div @slideInOut *ngSwitchCase="3"></div>
  <div @slideInOut *ngSwitchCase="4"></div>
</div>

<button (click)="handleNext()">Next</button>
```

app.component.scss

```
.container {
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { slideInOut } from './shared/animations';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [ slideInOut ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly name: string = 'Angular';
  counter = 1;

  boxArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  handleNext(){
    if(this.counter <= this.boxArr.length){
      this.counter += 1
    } else {
      this.counter = 1
    }
  }
}
```

animations.ts

```
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from "@angular/animations";


export const slideInOut =  trigger('slideInOut', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
      animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
    ])
])
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-na1ath

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the right link?

Comment: Nope, that was wrong. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that:

1) When you are dealing with `display: block` the element takes full line width no matter if there is some space left and therefore your slides were in two rows

2) If we solve this by adding `display: inline-block` we have to deal with that when there are two elements they take more space than one element. Meanwhile, `translate` doesn't actually move your element but only it's visible part (the "physical" shape is in the same position)

And thus it was solved by absolute positioning of your slides

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zciezz?file=src/app/app.component.scss

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
  }
}
```